# Angular 7 array change value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I am working on a complex array in which questions and its related answers are coming from the service. After receiving the array I want to change the attribute 'IsChecked' of the Answers to false. My code for this is

```
this.questions.forEach( elm => {
                  elm.Awnsers.forEach( ans => {
                    ans.IsChekced = false;
                  });
                });
```

and the output coming is

```
{Awnser: "Periapical radiograph(s).", IsChecked: true, Qid: 1, IsChekced: false}
```

As you can see instead of changing the value of IsChecked the code is adding another attribute with the same name. What is wrong am I doing?

Comment: IsChekced is the wrong key please change it IsChecked. please check the answer for detail

Comment: if you think our solution solved your problem then you accept the answer so that others will get benefit out of it thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misspelled the `IsChecked` key with `IsChekced`

Just update below code it will work.

```
this.questions.forEach( elm => {
                  elm.Awnsers.forEach( ans => {
                    ans.IsChecked= false;
                  });
                });
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

IsChekced is spelled incorrectly. It is not IsChecked

k <==> c

Answer (score 0):

Yes you just misspelled the IsChecked you can do this by below code

```
this.questions.forEach( elm => {
    elm.Awnsers.forEach( ans => {
      ans.IsChecked = false;
    });
  });
  console.log(this.questions);
```